# python ipycytoscape accesing a node by id

Tags: python, graph, ipywidgets, ipycytoscape

Assuming I have a ipycytoscape graph as follows:

```
railnet= '''{
    "nodes": [
        {"data": { "id": "BER", "label":"HBf BER", "classes":"east"}},
        {"data": { "id": "MUN", "label":"HBf MUN", "classes":"west"}},
        {"data": { "id": "FRA", "label":"HBf FRA", "classes":"west"}}
        ],
    "edges": [
        {"data": { "id": "line1", "source": "BER", "target": "MUN","label":"200km/h"}},
        {"data": { "id": "line2", "source": "MUN", "target": "FRA","label":"200km/h"}},
        {"data": { "id": "line3", "source": "FRA", "target": "BER","label":"250km/h" }}           
    ]
  }'''

railnetJSON = json.loads(railnet)
ipycytoscape_obj3 = ipycytoscape.CytoscapeWidget()
ipycytoscape_obj3.graph.add_graph_from_json(railnetJSON, directed=False) # I am telling I dont want directions
ipycytoscape_obj3
```

How can I access easily a node with the id?

this does not work:

```
ipycytoscape_obj3.graph.nodes['BER']. # --> wrong
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `id` information is inside of data.
I didn't test it but maybe `nodes['data']['BER']` would work?
You can check this [example](https://github.com/cytoscape/ipycytoscape/pull/271) for a bit more complex edge/node interaction. Check the Pandas session on this notebook. And as always, feel free to open an issue on the repo.
Thanks!